# Token Isuue in databricks Workspace Deplyoment through CI/CD of the Azure Devops

Tags: azure-active-directory, databricks, azure-databricks

I am Deploying an azure data bricks Workspace from one Databricks environment to another So we can manage our Development and Production workspaces INDependently, For that, we are using Microsoft Azure DevOps CI/CD and following the Microsoft Link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/implement-ci-cd-azure-devops/3-create-ci-cd-process

This link has all the steps and we have performed all the steps

1. To create a Build pipeline (in which we have to attach azure Devops and provide our Code repo)
2. To create the Release pipeline and link the artifacts of the previous build pipeline
3. Create a job in the release pipeline in which we have to use the Databricks Script Deployment Task by Data Thirst Extension which I had installed
4. After installing the extension we have to use Databricks Notebook Deployment. **In that, we have to provide the Databricks Personal Access Token** which I have provided taking access token from Dtabricks portal

On saving the Release and Deploying I Found an error that
[image]

Error 401 Invalid Databricks Personal Access Token. If you believe this is a mistake, please contact Databricks support.

HTTP ERROR 401
Problem accessing /api/2.0/workspace/mkdirs. Reason:
Invalid Databricks Personal Access Token. If you believe this is a mistake, please contact Databricks support.

But I have checked more than 4 times  I have generated and pasted the same token of the Databricks
but it is not taking it.

[image]

generated the Token From Databricks portal as shown in Picture.

Can anybody help me with it?

Comment: Check that you have both correct host & correct token. otherwise you can use databricks cli for copying notebook into another workspace

Comment: yup I have provided the Region wrong, now I have provided the Correct region 
problem solved thanks

Comment: I was also facing the similar issue. Yup now working for me too @Shubhamkumarjain